# Embedded linux RSA private key strategy

Tags: openssl, embedded

We have an embedded linux board running from an sdcard. The linux board creates some data files which have to be signed using a private key, so it later can be verified using a public key. This ensures that the data was infact created on that specific board and that is has not been tampered with.

Since the sdcard can be removed, it can easily be read and therefore it seems like a bad strategy to store the private key file on the sdcard (rootfs). 
Our idea was to generate the private key on boot and store it in ram. The seed for generating the private key could be read from some board chip IDs. Which would ensure that the key could not be read if the sdcard was removed.

But is this a good strategy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unattended Key Storage is a problem without a solution. It does not matter if your store it on the sdcard, burn it into ROM and blow the fuses, guard it with a smart card, guard it with a SIM, or guard it with a TPM. See Peter Gutmann's [Engineering Security](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/pubs/book.pdf).

Seeding a PRNG with a known value and then performing deterministic key generation is just a symptom of the underlying problem.

You have to determine your threats, determine how much risk you are willing to accept and then use a design the agrees with your security posture.